# Writing a blackjack console program in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment of making a blackjack like program in a class. My first problem I am dealing with is creating an array of the cards. The professor wants an array setup with a txt file with the following format.

```
2 of hearts
2 of diamonds
2 of spades
2 of clubs
3 of hearts
3 of diamonds
3 of spades
```

This goes on till face cards when it replaces the number with jack, queen, king, ace. Following the professors requirements, How would I take input from the txt file and just store the number and the hearts,diamonds,spades, and clubs. 
Thank you for the help

Comment: Remember nobody will do your homework for you here.

Comment: This did not deserve a -1.  +1 for balance's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line which you can split into its parts using the ' of ' as the separator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you heard about the Scanner class.

> But in case you haven't:
>   http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: But in case you haven't: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: Yeah, right, hope you don't mind if I add it to my answer.

Comment: If anyone is still following this... How can I do this array when I get face cards that say king,jack..ect. I do not know how to set something up that allows a string or an integer... Thanks

Comment: @user337465, well, A=1, J=11, Q=12, K=13, so you don't need to store them as strings

Answer (score 0):

Use the java.util.Scanner class, read in the file line by line, scan each line for the text 'of' to separate the card value from the card suit.

Comment: Since it's homework, I think the input file has a fixed format and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can read lines with a `Scanner` object. Let's say your setup file is in "cards.txt"

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("cards.txt));

while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine(); // each one of these will be like the "3 of Spades"
    // have code here to decode the line
}
```

This should point you in the right direction. Don't forget to import java.io.* (or .File) and java.util.* (or.Scanner)! :-)